# Not able to assign value to a list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am using a MVC application. This is my model.

```
public class Fruit
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Colors> ColorsList { get; set; }

}

public class Colors
{
    public string ColorId { get; set; }
    public string ColorName { get; set; }
    public string ColorDescription { get; set; }
}
```

And my query in Linq :

```
var lstfruits = db.Fruits.Select(c => new Fruit {Id=c.Id, Name = c.Name, Description = c.Description });

foreach (var fruit in lstfruits)
{
    var lstColor = new List<Colors>();
    lstColor = db.Color.Where(f => f.FruitId == fruit.Id)
                       .Select(f => new Colors {ColorId=f.Id.ToString(), ColorName = f.Name, ColorDescription = f.Description })
                       .ToList();
    fruit.ColorsList = lstColor;
}

return lstfruits;
```

While debugging the `lstColor` is not null after the query but `lstfruits` always has the value of `ColorsList = null` for all elements. What am I missing?

I know my queries are working fine because I do get expected values from both the queries on debug. The issue is assigning it to `fruits.ColorsList` inside the for loop.

Comment: Why are you transforming a Fruit into a Fruit and a Color into a Color? Remove those `.Select`

Comment: Your `Colors` class appears to be a single Color and not a list, is the `s` a mistake?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I did not understand the comment.I am trying to add the property ColorList to each value of fruit in the for loop.

Comment: Why can't the first line just be `var lstfruits = db.Fruits;` ?

Comment: @RobinBennett Because I want to associate the result with a model?

Comment: Also, the `Fruit` class doesn't have a `ColorId` property, although it's used later.

Comment: Could the problem be that both lambda expressions are using `f`, but the second one is referencing the `f` from the first expression?

Comment: Another minor point (that doesn't address the problem) is that you don't need to create `lstColor = new List<Colors>();
` before you use it. You could write `var lstColor = db.Color.Where(…`

Answer (score 1):

Convert your foreach to a For Loop.

```
for(int i=0;i<lstfruits.Count();i++)
{

    var lstColor = new List<Colors>();
    lstColor = db.Color.Where(f => f.FruitId == lstfruits[i].Id)
                       .Select(f => new Colors {ColorId=f.Id.ToString(), ColorName = f.Name, ColorDescription = f.Description })
                       .ToList();
    lstfruits[i].ColorsList = lstColor;
}
```

You could make actually do away List initialization within loop by

```
for(int i=0;i<lstfruits.Count();i++)
{

    lstfruits[i].ColorsList = db.Color.Where(f => f.FruitId == lstfruits[i].Id)
                       .Select(f => new Colors {ColorId=f.Id.ToString(), ColorName = f.Name, ColorDescription = f.Description })
                       .ToList();

}
```

Comment: I am trying to add ColorList using the for loop because I could not add it in the first query

Comment: @TheFallenOne I have updated the answer, could you check